# Selectores y eventos de JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

No estoy segura si es que yo me equivoqué o es que han habido cambios recientes en los estándares de JQuery, pero no me funciona el evento *click*, aparece tachado en el editor.

El código debe seleccionar las etiquetas `<p>` del Html y borrar la clase *zebra* en caso de que la tengan, cuando el usuario le hace *click*, y de este modo, en la pagina, debería reflejarse el cambio en el `<p>` afectado.

Aquí el código JS

```
var parrafos = $("p");
    parrafos.click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("zebra");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Observa como he creado varios párrafos, uno de eelos con una clase zebra (texto grande y negrita). Al pulsar sobre él la clase se desactiva.

```js
var parrafos = $("p");
    parrafos.click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("zebra");
    })
```

```css
.zebra{
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: black;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="zebra">parrafo 1</p>
<p>parrafo 2</p>
<p>parrafo 3</p>
<p>parrafo 4</p>
```

Comparar con tu código y seguro que encuentras el fallo.

Comment: Me gustaría añadir que click aparece tachado porque ha sido deprecado (que no eliminado por lo que sigue funcionando por ahora) de jQuery 3.0.0 (Fuente: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/main/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfnclick-event-shorthand-is-deprecated). Se debe de usar de ahora en adelante el metodo genérico de eventos: parrafos.on("click", function(){})